# What data should/should not be backed up for django website using python-social-auth ? Which sets of data are sensitive?

Tags: python, django, database-backups, python-social-auth

For a django site implementing python-social-auth to enable login, **exactly what should be backed up** and what should **NOT** be backed up? Should the entire tables created by social-auth be backed up? or should only certain data be exported and backed up?

Also, how does one test that the restore functionality works?

Comment: The table ``social_auth_usersocialauth`` is the critical one, the others are mostly to hold temporary values needed by OpenId auth.

Comment: Thx. Say last user created was at 10AM, Backup was done right after that. No new users were created, but existing users logged in, out, went to their providers (say google) and changed their info there, logged in, logged out from django site. The django site unfortunately loses the db. A new empty db is created, python manage sync/migrate, and then social_auth_usersocialauth is restored. Is that sufficient? What exactly will be missing after this?